# Making multiple asynchronous request using Retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit

In my android application I have a screen where I have 3 spinners that need to be 
filled from APIs call.

```
static List<TripCode> tripCodeList = new ArrayList<>();
static List<Fleet> truckList = new ArrayList<>();
static List<Trailer> trailerList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I don't want to inflate the layout unless I get the response from all the 3 different API calls so this is what I'm doing

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = this;

        if (MyApplication.isConnected()) {
            getTripCodes();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setContentView(R.layout.no_internet_connection);
        }
    }
```

Basically , I removed `setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_trip);`
from `onCreate()` And I called `getTripCodes()`

here's the code for `getTripCodes()`

```
   public void getTripCodes() {

        MyApplication.showProgressDialog(getString(R.string.please_wait), this);
        IMyAPI iMyAPI = MyApplication.getIMyAPI();
        Call<List<TripCode>> call = iMyAPI.getTripCodes();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<TripCode>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TripCode>> call, Response<List<TripCode>> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    tripCodeList = response.body();
                    Log.d("test", "getTripCodes success = " + tripCodeList.size());
                    getTrucks();
                } else {
                    MyApplication.dismissProgressDialog();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TripCode>> call, Throwable t) {
                MyApplication.dismissProgressDialog();
            }
        });

    }
```

So in the success of the call I'm calling the other function `getTrucks()` which also get result from API and in the success it will call `getTrailers()`

But I think it's a waste of time, because I can call the three function all together in parallel, and then check if all the list are filled or not.

But I don't know how to do it. How can I check if all the calls are success? And if one of them has failed, how will I know which one exactly failed?

Comment: **I can call the three function all together in parallel**, I would say there are many ways. Learn **RxJava** or **Multi-Threading**, if using Kotlin then Coroutines are recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe for your problem you can easily use Retrofit 2.6.0 which has coroutine support and you can declare all the function's as suspended function's and dispatch them with `async/launch` dispatcher and if you want to wait for some result in some case use `await()` to wait for the result.

And use RxJava/liveData for responsive UI

sample code for you will look like

```
//maybe from Activity for ViewModel you can use ViewModelScope
GlobalScope.launch{
 result1= async{ getTripCodes() }
 result2= async{ getTrucks() }
 result3= async{ getTrailers() }
 doSomethingWithTripCodes(result1.await())
 doSomethingWIthTrucks(result2.await())
 doSomethingTrailers(result3.await())
}
```

Reference:

- [post1](https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067)